# What is the probability of getting exactly one ace if i drew 4 cards at random from a standard deck of 52 playing cards?

Tags: probability, combinations

I used combinations and got (4C1*48C3)/52C4 which roughly comes out to be 0.256 which is ~26%. I'm not sure if this is correct or not.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  A good sanity check is to imagine that we were drawing with replacement (clearly just an approximation).  then the answer would be $4\times \frac 1{13}\times \left( \frac {12}{13} \right)^3\approx .242$ which is indeed close to your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. There is another way to solve this though:

Probability of drawing the ace in the first draw:
$P_1 = 4/52\times48/51\times47/50\times46/49$

Probability of drawing the ace in the second draw:
$P_2 = 48/52\times4/51\times47/50\times46/49$

Probability of drawing the ace in the third draw:
$P_3 = 48/52\times47/51\times4/50\times46/49$

Probability of drawing the ace in the fourth draw:
$P_4 = 48/52\times47/51\times46/50\times4/49$

So, the probability of drawing exactly one ace $= P_1 + P_2 + P_3 + P_4 = 4 \times P_1=25.56\%$

Comment: Ah I see, thank you very much.